# How to send query (react query) when submitting form (react hook form) with button click and passing params in query key

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

I'm struggling with something in react query that I have in multiple cases.

I have a form that triggers a filter query, and a component rendering the results.

In my query I want to pass the filters in query key so that it can cache data if we trigger twice the same filters.

However, I don't want the query to be automatically triggered whenever I change a filter, but when I click on a submit button.

I could managed it with a custom state that is changed when I submit the form, but I don't like this way since it makes me create a state with some value that I just have.

How can I manage this ?

I got my first component DetailedReport as this :

```
export function DetailedReport() {
  let defaultStartDate = dayjs().startOf("month").subtract(1, "month");
  let defaultEndDate = dayjs().endOf("month");

  const { handleSubmit, control, getValues, setValue, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      start_date: defaultStartDate,
      end_date: defaultEndDate,
      note: "",
      users: [],
      works: [],
    },
  });

  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["reports", "detailed", getValues()],
    queryFn: () => loadDetailedActivity(getValues()),
    enabled: watch("users").length > 0,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("on usbmit", data);

    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
      <div className="text-3xl font-bold text-slate-600">Rapport détaillé</div>
      <Paper elevation={2} className="mb-5 flex flex-col gap-5 p-5">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Form
          isLoading={isLoading}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          control={control}
          setValue={setValue}
          // searchParams={searchParams}
          // setSearchParams={setSearchParams}
        />
       </form>
        
          <div><Reports reports={reports} /></div>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
```

Then, in my form I got this :

```
export function Form({ isLoading, control, setValue }) {
  const { managedUsers } = useGetMyManagedUsers({
    enabled: true,
  });
  const { users, isLoading: isLoadingUsers } = useGetUsers({
    enabled: true,
  });

  // Populate users for form because autocomplete default value is not init
  // on first render since request hasn't finished yet
  useEffect(() => {
    if (managedUsers) setValue("users", managedUsers);
  }, [managedUsers, setValue]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-5">
        <div>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            size="large"
            disabled={isLoading}
            variant="contained"
          >
            {isLoading ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                className="fa-spin m-auto text-xl"
                icon={faSpinner}
              />
            ) : (
              "Envoyer"
            )}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ minWidth: "315px" }} className="flex">
        {
          isLoadingUsers ? (
            <Skeleton variant="rounded" width={"315px"} height={"56px"} />
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Controller
                name="users"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    options={
                      hasPermission("VIEW_OTHERS_TIME_WORK")
                        ? users
                        : managedUsers
                    }
                    value={value}
                    limitTags={3}
                    multiple
                    onChange={(test, data) => {
                      onChange(data);
                    }}
                    // onChange={(e, values) => setValue("users", values)}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.fullName}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                      option.id === value.id
                    }
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label={"Utilisateurs"}
                        sx={{
                          "& .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error": {
                            position: "absolute",
                            top: "100%",
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT** : I believe that the issue comes from Autocomplete that would re-trigger render of getValues wherease it shouldn't. When I'm doing the test with a standard input, it doesn't retrigger automaticcaly, and I can use refetch() of rhf to trigger the query correctly.

**EDIT 2** : A normal text field is not triggering when typing, however when submitting form, it triggers twice

Comment: you probably need to provide a minimal codesandbox example to simulate the behavior.
But one thing that it's questionable is your `queryKey: ["reports", "detailed", getValues()]`, where `getValues()` seems like can trig a lot of api calls if the form is keep changing. I believe the logic itself is pretty problematic, you might need to rethink your UI logic. Or you might a debouncer for it. In general, you shouldn't pass it directly from hook form to react query with such a logic. It's hard to reason what will happen back and forth without a throttler.

Comment: The only solution I can come up with, is to have the handlesubmit form in the Form Component. Then in the parent, I have a state searchParams, which I give the the Form component. When I submit the form, then I update searchParams, which is given to the queryKey. It works well, but it makes me duplicate the logic for initialization. I'll keep it like this for now since I can't find a better solution.